# MPICH2 Out of Memory when sending an INT

Tags: mpi, mpich

I've been working all week to try and get a 3 machine cluster running torque+mpich2. My plan is to use it as my development environment and eventually run the production code out in EC2 or some other cloud. Since it is a development environment, I'm just using some spare machines (2 64-bit, 1 32-bit in case that matters). The machines are using various distro's of Ubuntu (maverick, hardy, and karmic).

The problem that I am encountering is that on a simple send/recv test program I made the recv call appears to be running out of memory and I have no idea why. ~1.2G of RAM free on the machine with 1 int being sent/recved.

Heres the code:

```
/*
 * A very simple send/recv program
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define MAXHOSTNAMELEN 64

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int pid, from;
    int nproc;
    MPI_Status status;
    int to_recv;
    int to_send = 1;
    char hostname[MAXHOSTNAMELEN];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);

    gethostname(hostname, MAXHOSTNAMELEN);
    printf("%d of %d:%s Checking in\n", pid, nproc, hostname);

    if (pid == 0) {
        MPI_Recv(&to_recv, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        from = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        printf("%d of %d:%s Recieved Value %d from %d\n", pid, nproc, hostname, to_recv, from);

        MPI_Recv(&to_recv, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        from = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        printf("%d of %d:%s Recieved Value %d from %d\n", pid, nproc, hostname, to_recv, from);
    } else {
        MPI_Send(&to_send, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("%d of %d:%s Sent value\n", pid, nproc, hostname);
    }   

    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(0);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
0 of 3:master Checking in
2 of 3:node1 Checking in
1 of 3:node2 Checking in
1 of 3:node2 Sent value
Fatal error in MPI_Recv: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Recv(186)...........................: MPI_Recv(buf=0x7fff33bed040, count=1, MPI_INT, src=2, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x7fff33bed020) failed
MPIDI_CH3I_Progress(402)................: 
MPID_nem_mpich2_blocking_recv(905)......: 
MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1838).............: 
state_commrdy_handler(1676).............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_recv_handler(1564).........: 
MPID_nem_handle_pkt(636)................: 
MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_EagerShortSend(441): Out of memory
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Send(173)..............: MPI_Send(buf=0x7fff8ee5396c, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=0, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1826): Communication error with rank 0: Connection refused
```

If there is any necessary information that I haven't include please let me know and I will add it.

MPICH2 Version: mpich2-1.4.1p1 compiled from source on each machine
gcc versions:
 master: 4.2.4
 node1: 4.4.5
 node2: 4.4.1

Also, in case it is important, node2 is the 32-bit machine. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**: I ran this on a cluster I have used in the past which is setup and known working in order to test the code. The code appears to work correctly, I believe the problem I am seeing is related to the configuration of MPI on my development cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, MPICH2 does not support heterogeneous platforms.  You could build MPICH2 and your application for 32-bit and run that on all machines.